# Is Convexity necessary to use Gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, gradient-descent, convex

I was reading and I saw that convexity is sufficient for using GD to minimize functions. Would it be also necessary?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the global minimum exists, no, as per the statement, convexity is sufficient, not necessary. Without convexity, gradient descent is not guaranteed to find the global optimum, but it might. It'll find a local optimum though, assuming a proper learning rate/policy is applied.